# How to select count of children in a hierarchical table based on a filter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table `TableA`:

```
parent_id int
this_id int
filter int
this_date date
```

And some sample data:

```
parent_id = 1, this_id = 1, filter = 1, this_date = ...
parent_id = 1, this_id = 2, filter = 0, this_date = ...
parent_id = 1, this_id = 3, filter = 1, this_date = ...
parent_id = 4, this_id = 4, filter = 0, this_date = ...
parent_id = 4, this_id = 5, filter = 0, this_date = ...
parent_id = 4, this_id = 6, filter = 1, this_date = ...
parent_id = null, this_id = 7, filter = 0, this_date = ...
parent_id = null, this_id = 8, filter = 1, this_date = ...
```

The `parent_id` is always the same as one of the children's `this_id`. If there are no children then `parent_id` is null

The table can't change, that's what we have.

I have created a view to give me summaries:

```
SELECT ISNULL(parent_id,this_id) id, COUNT(*) numparts, MAX(this_date)...
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ISNULL(parent_id,this_id)
```

I want to add to my summary view the number of parts that have `filter=1`.

So my results for this example (if I do a `SELECT * FROM theview`) would be:

```
id  numparts dt    numOfFilter1
1      3     ...        2
4      3     ...        1
7      1     ...        0
8      1     ...        1
```

In reality my filter column will be a sub-query but I think I can figure that bit out once I have this bit sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(parent_id,this_id) id, 
        COUNT(*) numparts, 
        MAX(this_date), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN filter = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) numOfFilter1
FROM    TableA
GROUP BY 
        ISNULL(parent_id,this_id)
```

Comment: The count does not work, but your answer led me to the correct one.  Just change count to sum - thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Exactly, I used this before but I overlooked the function (`SUM` instead of `COUNT`), well spotted.